# Get-WinEvent - Expand Property $_.Message to get full message details?

Tags: powershell

How can I get the full Event ID Detailed content from the below code?
Because of the **$_.Message** variable seems to be truncated?

From this script:

```
$EventIDs = 5829, 5830, 5831, 5827, 5828, 5719
$Ago = -240
$EventFilter = @{ LogName = 'System'; ID = $EventIDs; StartTime = (Get-Date).AddHours($Ago) }

    Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=computer)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=8192))" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Sort-Object | ForEach-Object {
    
        $computer = $_
        Write-Host "Processing $computer ..."
            Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $_ -FilterHashTable $EventFilter |
                    Select-Object -Property TimeCreated, Id, @{N='Detailed Message'; E={$_.Message}} | 
                    Sort-Object -Property TimeCreated
    } | OGV -Title "Checking NETLOGON $($EventIDs) AD Domain Controllers as at $(Get-Date -Format 'F')"
```

Comment: if you leave off the `Out-GridView` call ... do you see the whole thing?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey it is still the same. Somehow it is truncated ?

Comment: the PoSh display system will truncate things that are "too wide". however, that is only the _display_, not the actual value. are you certain that the VALUE is being truncated?

Comment: Yes it is truncated when I expand the column in OGV. So would it be possible to get the complete event details? Or exporting to CSV is better ?

Comment: that is not what i asked. [*grin*] **_if you leave off the `O-GV` call ... do you see the item truncated? what happens if you pipe that to `Format-List`? what happens if you save all of it to a $Var and then use `$Var.Message` to get just that one value, is it truncated? ///// also, if you look at the properties of `$Var[0].Message` do you see more than one property?

Comment: i don't have those events in my `System` log, so i used `232` [Hyper-V-VMSwitch]. that shows truncated on the `O-GV` display ... but it show the full text when i hover over it.

Comment: Yes, that does make sense @Lee_Dailey, thank you it is working as expected.

Comment: kool! you are most welcome! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to pipe Get-WinEvent to Select-Object -ExpandProperty and select Property "Detailed Message"

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable $EventFilter | Select-Object -Property TimeCreated, Id, 
@{N='Detailed Message'; E={$_.Message}} | Sort-Object -Property TimeCreated | Select- 
Object -ExpandProperty 'Detailed Message'
```

Comment: Thanks, @losfla, so now the result is just this one particular column 'Detailed Message', not the one I selected before.

Comment: Filter left, format right!